# Export Data to csv files from Neo4j pragmatically

Tags: neo4j, export-to-csv, neo4j-java-api, neo4j-apoc

I need your advice on neo4j export things…. I used ” apoc.export.cypher.query” to export my nodes and relationships to csv files , however the exported contents are cypher statements. This is a sample exported csv file :

```
begin
CREATE (:`ITEM`:`UNIQUE IMPORT LABEL` {`product_number`:5305, `bi_key`:1910, `mean_review_score`:“4.42”, `review_count`:“24", `site_availability_bitmask`:“2129759”, `UNIQUE IMPORT ID`:117});
CREATE (:`ITEM`:`UNIQUE IMPORT LABEL` {`product_number`:7123, `bi_key`:2261, `UNIQUE IMPORT ID`:121});
CREATE (:`ITEM`:`UNIQUE IMPORT LABEL` {`product_number`:7436, `bi_key`:2330, `mean_review_score`:“4.41", `review_count`:“117”, `site_availability_bitmask`:“2113295", `UNIQUE IMPORT ID`:125});
CREATE (:`ITEM`:`UNIQUE IMPORT LABEL` {`product_number`:7697, `bi_key`:2382, `UNIQUE IMPORT ID`:130});
CREATE (:`ITEM`:`UNIQUE IMPORT LABEL` {`product_number`:7743, `bi_key`:2388, `mean_review_score`:“4.33”, `review_count`:“18", `site_availability_bitmask`:“2113295”, `UNIQUE IMPORT ID`:133});
commit
begin
CREATE INDEX ON :`ITEM`(`product_number`);
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (node:`UNIQUE IMPORT LABEL`) ASSERT node.`UNIQUE IMPORT ID` IS UNIQUE;
commit
schema await
begin
MATCH (n:`UNIQUE IMPORT LABEL`)  WITH n LIMIT 10 REMOVE n:`UNIQUE IMPORT LABEL` REMOVE n.`UNIQUE IMPORT ID`;
commit
begin
DROP CONSTRAINT ON (node:`UNIQUE IMPORT LABEL`) ASSERT node.`UNIQUE IMPORT ID` IS UNIQUE;
commit
```

---

But this is not what I want , is there anyway to export graph content directly to csv files with csv formats? Or I should rely on parsing the file above ... or using neo4j jdbc driver to execute cypher and write the result in csv ?
I need to do this pragmatically … I mean it is a web application from which users should be able to extract graph content to csv formats

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Instead of using `apoc.export.cypher.query` you can use `apoc.export.csv.query` to write the results to a CSV file. For example:

```
CALL apoc.export.csv.query("MATCH (u:User)-[r:RATED]->(m:Movie) RETURN u.name, r.rating, m.title LIMIT 10", "results.csv", {})
```

More info in the docs [here](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_export_to_csv)

Answer (score -1):

the method apoc.export.csv() seems super slow.

I'm running a VM with neo4j.
My procedure is to have a dictionary of cypher queries to be executed through a python script running in the background... All good.

The last step of the python script to execute the exportation query, for a node with 27M unique records and all their properties (maybe 10 columns). this is the cypher query:

```
with collect(distinct r) as my_stuff
call apoc.export.csv.data(my_stuff, [], 'neo4j_output.csv', {})
    yield file, source, format, nodes, properties, time, rows, batchSize, batches, done, data
    return file, source, format, nodes, properties, time, rows, batchSize, batches, done, data, size(researcher)
```

It lasted 40 mins to populate the database from a GCP bucket... But it's lasting way more in exporting the data to the default path `/var/lib/neo4j/import/`.

Any insights of how speeding things up are welcome